# VB Script is taking too long to search for a match in the log file

Tags: logging, search, vbscript, match

I have a piece of code (running on WINDOWS 10) which searches for a match in the log files and prints the match to an output file on the mentioned path.

The script does its job very well and searches the match correctly.
Only problem I am facing is that the script is taking too long (on average 12 hours) to search for the match in a single file. (a single file is carrying on average 135,800 lines and each line is carrying on average 1500 characters)
The computer specs are: intel i7 10th Gen (6 cores, 12 thread), 16 GB RAM,

How can this script be further optimized to reduce the search time?

```
'Wscript.Echo ("Script STARTED @" &Now)

'This will get the generic "desktop-path" for all of the users
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
userName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%UserName%" )
DesktopPath = "C:\Users\" & userName & "\Desktop\Logs\"
'ends here

'Defines the pattern
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = Inputbox("Enter the pattern to search for","PATTERN","Enter pattern here:")
'ends here

'Defines the general object for all purposes i.e. reading, writing, creating etc
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading = 1

Set LogsFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Inputbox("Enter the path to the log files","LOG FILES", DesktopPath))
NewNohupPath = Inputbox("Enter the path to save the output file","OUTPUT FILE", DesktopPath)
Set Nohup = objFSO.CreateTextFile(NewNohupPath &"nohup.txt")
Nohup.WriteLine("Default log_path= C:\Users\Ahsan.Taqveem\Desktop")
Nohup.WriteLine("")
Nohup.WriteLine("Script STARTED @" &Now)
Nohup.WriteLine("--")
for each LogFile in LogsFolder.Files
    if lcase(objFSO.getExtensionName(LogFile.path))="log" then
        Set SelectedLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(LogFile.path, ForReading)
        Do While Not SelectedLogFile.AtEndOfStream
            CurrentLine = SelectedLogFile.readline
            Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(CurrentLine)
            If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
                For Each strMatch in colMatches
                    Nohup.WriteLine(CurrentLine)
                Next
            End If
        Loop
        SelectedLogFile.Close
    End if
Next

'Almost done, finishing stage
Nohup.WriteLine("--")
Nohup.WriteLine("Script FINISHED @" &Now)
Nohup.WriteLine("")
Nohup.WriteLine("")

'Close the opened output file
Nohup.Close

'saves the custom date format for renaming the file
CustomeDate = FormatDateTime(Now, vbShortDate) & "_" & right("0" & hour(time),2) & right("0" & minute(time),2) & right("0" & second(time),2)

'its just renaming the file - appending the date at the start of the file name
objFSO.MoveFile NewNohupPath &"nohup.txt", NewNohupPath & CustomeDate &"-nohup.txt"

'End of script
Wscript.Echo("Script FINISHED @" &Now)
```

Comment: There are long established tools that you can use that are better than rolling your own.   grep, for example - or get-content in Powershell.

Comment: You might want to change the tag from vb.net to vbscript, as this doesn't have any vb.net content.

Comment: @Craig it was mistakenly written. Thanks for correcting it.

Comment: Take a look at [sift](https://sift-tool.org/). Here are some [benchmarks](https://sift-tool.org/performance)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just searching for a specific string, e.g. want to find all lines that contain "ID", using the `InStr()` function is significantly faster that using RegEx.

To search using `InStr()`, you need the string you want to search in and the text you want to search for:
`InStr(stringToSearchIn, stringToFind)`.
When the `InStr()` function finds a match, it will return the position in the string where the match was found (and will return 0 if no match is found). See [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) for more details on the funciton.

You can use this in an `If` statement to only write lines that match your search criteria like so:

```
If InStr(CurrentLine, searchString) >= 1 Then
    Nohup.WriteLine(CurrentLine)
End If
```

Comment: Yes, searching for a specific string, this should be about 7 times faster than the posted script. That would reduce the wait to abut 2.75 hours. However, the lack of pattern matching is probably not acceptable. If the script were modified to use the [Sift](https://sift-tool.org/) command line search tool it would run about 34 times faster, reducing the wait to about 21 minutes, without giving up regex pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Sift](https://sift-tool.org/) command line tool to do the regex search. On tests with 10MB log files, the search was approximately 34 times faster than the original script. Here's the script modified to use sift:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForAppending = 8
Const CmdHide = 0
Const CmdShow = 1
Const Wait2Finish = True

userName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%UserName%" )
DesktopPath = "C:\Users\" & userName & "\Desktop\Logs\"

Pattern = Inputbox("Enter the search pattern:","PATTERN","Enter pattern here")
If Pattern="" Then WScript.Quit
LogsFolder = Inputbox("Enter the path to the log files","LOG FILES", DesktopPath)
If LogsFolder="" Then WScript.Quit
NewNohupPath = Inputbox("Enter the path to save the output file","OUTPUT FILE", DesktopPath)
If NewNohupPath="" Then WScript.Quit

Set oLogsFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(LogsFolder)
NohupFilePath = NewNohupPath &"nohup.txt"
Set Nohup = objFSO.CreateTextFile(NohupFilePath)

Nohup.WriteLine("Script STARTED @" & Now)
Nohup.WriteLine("--")
Nohup.Close

For Each LogFile In oLogsFolder.Files
  If lcase(objFSO.getExtensionName(LogFile.path))="log" Then
    wshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c sift.exe """ & Pattern & """ """ & LogFile.path & """>>""" & NohupFilePath & """",CmdShow,Wait2Finish
  End If
Next

Set Nohup = objFSO.OpenTextFile(NohupFilePath,ForAppending)

Nohup.WriteLine("--")
Nohup.WriteLine("Script FINISHED @" & Now)
Nohup.WriteLine("")
Nohup.WriteLine("")

Nohup.Close
```